# Website to search for android libs to use inside build.gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-studio

I remember there was a website where you could search for android libraries and it would give you an url which you could use in your build.gradle file, like this:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
    compile '<an-url-you-would-put-here>'
}
```

Unfortunately I can't find it anymore, does anyone know about it? I think it was hosted on appspot.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for [this.](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/)